# Worst-case time complexity of an algorithm with 2+ steps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, amortized-analysis

My goal is to write an algorithm that checks if an unsorted array of positive integers contains a value x and x^2 and return their indices if so.
I've solved this by proposing that first you sort the array using merge sort, then perform binary search for x, then perform binary search for x^2.
I then wrote that "since binary search has worst-case runtime of O(log n) and merge sort has worst-case runtime of O(n log n), we conclude that the worst-case runtime of this algorithm is O(n log n)." Am I correct in my understanding that when analyzing the overall efficiency of an algorithm that involves steps with different runtimes, we just take the one with the longest runtime? Or is it more involved than this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing an n in the claim, the result is O(nlogn), and yes in theory you just take the worst runtime. In practice the two marts might influence each other in a way that results in a different runtime. But I don't think it needs to be nlogn in the first place. You need no searching and no sorting, try iterating the list once and always add x and x^2 into a Map with the index as the value. Before adding check if x or x^2 are already there. If either are there you have found a match and are done. O(n). If your list can contain duplicates you need to track a bit more information in the map

Comment: @derpirscher typo on my part, fixed in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Since `O(log n) < O(n log n)`:

`O(n log n) +  O(log n) +  O(log n) = O(n log n)`

So the time complexity of the hole algorithm is  `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambigous. Do you get

1. an unsorted list `[a,b,c ...]` and a specific `x` to search for as parameter?

or

2. just get  the list and have to find if there is at least one pair `(x,y)` with `x^2 = y` contained in the list?

Now as you have cleared it's the first, the answer is *O(n)*, because you just have to iterate over the list (no need to sort or binary search) and check for each element if it's equal to `x` or `x^2`. If you find both, the list fulfills the condition.

```
function match(list, x) {
  let ix = -1, ixx = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i< list.length && (ix == -1 || ixx == -1); i++) {
    if (i == x) ix = i;
    if (i == x*x) ixx = i;
  }
  return [ix, ixx];
}
```

This returns the indexes of `x` and `x^2` or, if not found `-1` for the respective index. It returns, once both values are found in the list

Comment: Sorry, it's given a specific input x, find if the array contains the x and the x^2

Comment: @liatkatz wait, you are literally only searching for a single x and x^2 instead of trying to find any two values such that v1=v2^2? Then it is trivially possible in O(n), simply iterate once and save the index whenever you see x or x^2, I would not consider calling that algorithm given how basic its logic is...